# spring login by social account

Tags: spring, spring-social

In spring social is it possible to allow a user to login application using his social account?

I think only logged in user can connect their account with social account,if there is a user who is not registered in application and we want to allow him to login the application,it is not possible because when we create connectionRepository then we have to pass userid.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/signin.html

Answer (score 3):

what you need is to define

```
@Bean(name="connectionFactoryLocator")
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookId,facebookSecret));
    return registry;
}

@Bean
public UsersConnectionRepository socialConnectionRepository() {
    return new SocialConnectionRepository(dataSource, userRepository, connectionFactoryLocator());
}
```

where user repository is for example spring data jpa repository to read/write to your users table in db.

Then you can use controller provided by spring-social  ( not needed do define as bean if you use default conf )

```
  @Bean
  public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
    ProviderSignInController providerSignInController = new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator(), socialConnectionRepository(),
            new SimpleSignInAdapter());
    providerSignInController.setSignInUrl("/");
    providerSignInController.setSignUpUrl("/");
    return providerSignInController;
}
```

look into it on which paths you have to post your username/password ( by default its /signin/facebook )

If you need to log in user by spring security or do something special with info from fb then you have to define adapter:

```
private class SimpleSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
    public String signIn(String userId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried,break point inside signIn not working,seems flow is not correct

Comment: I have added a signinadapter but signin method is not getting called,can you help in finding the issue?

Comment: maybe your ProviderSignInController is not registered, do you use spring mvc? Turn on spring logs (in log4j.properties file) and check if there is any information about ProviderSignInController. Hard to help without any details :)

Comment: ProviterSignInController can't find a local user associated with a proviter user attempting to sign in, there may be an opportunity to have the user sign up with the application.

Then i come to know that it is redirecting to signup url as initially no local user is found.so on signup i can save user and then on next time it is redirecting me too login call successfully,but now question is,is there any way so that user is automatically created first time,and second question is,spirng social uses USERCONNECTION table for user storage,can i configure this to use another table?

Comment: 1. in sign in method you can save user id db and log in using spring security ( you can find how to do that in code on SO ).
2. no, in version which I was using it had to be USERCONNECTION - no configuration was allowed. Have no idea if its configurable in most recent release